# How to make notification icons stay stuck to top-right corner of box?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have used absolute positioning to position notification icons to the top-right corner of a box but when the screen size changes the notification icons move away from where they should be positioned.

[How the image should loook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMA9L.png)

[How image looks when screen size is adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM2Es.png)

How can I get them to stay where they should?

Comment: ..but it looks like you aren't setting a positioning *context* using `position:relative` on the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your component and the badge notification in a

```
<div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
 <component />
 <badge style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0 }} />
</div>
```

The wrapping div should keep the 'absolute' position of the badge within the div. So when your components get resized, the div gets resized, and thus your badge sticks within the div.